# Regular expression to match the input string

Tags: c#, regex

Regular expression to match the input string  is "Chart for - FName MName LName(ID)"  where FName, MName, LName and ID are alphanumric and can change at run time. for example it can be

> chart for -Anshul Srivastava (10GF12)
>
> chart for - Vidya sagar gupta(101)
>
> chart for - Avul Pakir Jainulabdeen Abdul Kalam(1097F)

I am new to Regex and try to build as

```
/Chart for -/-\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s/\(([^)]+)\)$/
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Please show your code and input and (expected) output. "Not working"  is not clear enough. Regexes in .NET don't need delimiters (`/.../`).

Comment: What does "not working" entail? what does it match that its not supposed to etc?

Comment: it means it should match the complete input string in format "Chart for - FName MName LName(ID)"

Comment: what's the rule to determine which of those is a middle name? and if two names only, do we assume those are first and last? can there only be one first name? how about only one middle? - do you need to extract these or just match the line?

Comment: How is it possible to know which parts of the name are `FName`, which are `MName` and which are `LName`. For example in the case of `Avul Pakir Jainulabdeen Abdul Kalam`?

Comment: static bool MatchInputFormat(string Input){  var strRegex = @"/Chart for -/-\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s/\(([^)]+)\)$/";
                Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
                string strTargetString = @"Chart for - Alok Aswal (1021)"; var match= myRegex.Matches(strTargetString); if(match.Success) return true; return false ;  somthing like this

Comment: I does not bother about whether FName Lname or Mname I does only care about My string should have 3 part first is constant ie. chart for- second is any name may have space between Fname and Lanme and thrid part is ID in paranthesis

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use any complex regex only to validate.

```
chart for -[\w\s]+\(\w*?\)$
```

In your regex you have capital `C` (in Chart)  this could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
/chart for -[a-z0-9 ()]+/i
```

your can use [this link](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expression with examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are great sites that help you to validate your regexp for example http://regexpal.com/

If the example text you posted is really that unstructured this regexp will do it:

```
chart for -[A-Za-z ]*\([0-9A-Za-z]*\)
```

If it's a bit more structured, like always a space after the first `-`and before the `( )` then you also could make the regexp a bit more precise.